# Android app interface like g+

Tags: android, android-layout

How can i implement a design like this image

[image: Google plus app]

i searched a lot and didn't find anything useful. Can anyone give me a starting point to create an interface like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some source library that dose just what you need .
Please follow below link . I hope it helps you .

[Google Plus Profile Screen](http://antoine-merle.com/blog/2013/10/04/making-that-google-plus-profile-screen/#comment-1167222784) & [Android-Parallax](https://github.com/kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager)